# ansible python error : No module named os

Tags: python, ansible

I am getting the below error when deploying for the first time to a host using ansible.

I've tried using the default setup (I believe this is using default python 3.6 version on the system). I ve also attempted to add in the inventory a variable to use python 2.6(ansible_python_interpreter = /usr/bin/python2.6)

Same error :

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared 
connection to myserverxx closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "'import site' 
failed; use -v for traceback\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File 
\"/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1531332066.08- 
249430258979920/setup.py\", line 4, in <module>\r\n    import 
os\r\nImportError: No module named os\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

On the host I can login and use python 3.6 interpreter and run import os (no error here).

EDIT : 
example of command that fails. I have the issue with a ping, seems configuration issue (with python?).

```
ansible -m ping dev_myserver -i ansible-hosts
```

Content of ansible-hosts

```
[dev_myserver]
servername ansible_user=username
```

Comment: Can you share your commands or playbooks?

Comment: I've added the simple ping command I run to get the error. Guessing sth is wrong with python, but the setup looks just fine on the host (I can run import os for example in python and it does not complain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by python installation on the environment, nothing wrong with ansible (was able to reproduce the error while logged in locally).